# Upstart for monitoring forking daemon?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ubuntu, upstart, init.d

According to [this link](http://tech.cueup.com/blog/2013/03/08/running-daemons/), it said

> Upstart is one of the best options for running traditional forking
>   daemons, since it actually uses ptrace to make sure it's watching the
>   correct process ids.

Now consider the case of **Apache httpd** running in pre-fork mode,  can anyone explain why using **Upstart** is better than the traditional init script's **pid** file approach?

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that apache crashes and you need to restart it. Upstart will do it. I personally prefer `supervisord` since it can also run in userspace but upstart is very good.

Comment: Actually `supervisord` is unable to monitor a forked daemon. Upstart is better in this case by the `expect` directive.